# Get the Next Upcoming Time from an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, utc

I am trying to get the next upcoming Time(In hours) from an array of times. The way it should work is it goes through the array of times (5:00, 10:00, etc.) and determines which will come next based on the current time. These times are in UTC.

Right now, what I've tried doing is making an array of dates on that day with those times. Depending on the time, however, this could produce an array of dates in which all of have already passed. To prevent this after checking to find the closest time, if the index is negative, it adds a day to every date in the array and then loops through it again.

Currently, my code just gives me the current time. Could anyone help me figure out how to make it work as described in the first paragraph?

My Current Code:

```js
let dates = [new Date().setHours(5, 0, 0, 0), new Date().setHours(10, 0, 0, 0), new Date().setHours(15, 0, 0, 0), new Date().setHours(20, 0, 0, 0)]

let index = null;

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  if (!index || dates[i] - new Date() < index) {
    index = dates[i] - new Date()
  }
}

if (Math.sign(index) == -1) {
  index = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    dates[i] = dates[i] + 86400000;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (!index || dates[i] - new Date() < index) {
      index = dates[i] - new Date()
    }
  }

  console.log(new Date(new Date() + index))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I was able to solve my question. There were many changes that needed to be made. The following code works as intented.

```js
let dateObject = new Date();
let dates = [dateObject.setUTCHours(5, 0, 0, 0), dateObject.setUTCHours(10, 0, 0, 0), dateObject.setUTCHours(15, 0, 0, 0), dateObject.setUTCHours(20, 0, 0, 0)]
let nextDate = null;

// Get the current date and time in UTC
let now = new Date();
now.setUTCDate(now.getUTCDate());
now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours());
now.setUTCMinutes(now.getUTCMinutes());
now.setUTCSeconds(now.getUTCSeconds());

// Loop through the dates array
for (let date of dates) {
  // Convert the date from a number to a Date object
  date = new Date(date);

  // If the date is later than the current date, log it and break out of the loop
  if (date > now) {
    nextDate = date;
    break;
  }
}
if (!nextDate) {
  nextDate = new Date(dates[0] + 86400000);
}
console.log(nextDate);
```

Comment: `now.setUTCDate(now.getUTCDate());` and following `setUTC…` statements do absolutely nothing useful. They simply set an existing value to exactly the same value. What do you think they're doing? I.e. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RobG I was trying to make sure the time is in UTC and consistent for everyone. Time zones should not affect how this runs.

Comment: ECMAScript *Date* objects are inherently UTC, they are just an offset in milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970 UTC. System regional settings are used for the non–UTC *set*, *get* and *toString* methods (and mosts parsing, but don't use the built–in parser). To keep things UTC, just use *UTC* methods.